# HTML5 canvas how to split circle to X parts

Tags: html, canvas, geometry

I need split circle to X parts without white center

`I have already this code: http://jsfiddle.net/U2tPJ/78/`
**I get this result:**

[image]

**I need finish result like this *(without white center)*:**

[image]

Comment: is it possible that those pies can be clickable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since what you want is to fill a part of the circle, use fill(), not stroke().

• The shape you want to draw (a pie) starts in the circle center :

```
ctx.moveTo(x,y);
```

Then follow the arc :

```
 context.arc(x, y, radius, i*pieAngle, (i+1)*pieAngle, false);
```

Then fill().

• Notice that the `segmentDepth` you were using was in fact an angle in degree. To clarify i used :

```
// size of a pie : it is an angle in radians
var pieAngle = 2 * Math.PI / hours;
```

• Lastly i used hsl colors to easily get a bunch of colors different for each hour :

```
    var hueValue = i * 15;
    context.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + hueValue + ',70%, 60%)';
```

result look this way :

[image]

draw code

```
function drawSegments(radius) {
    for (var i = 0; i < hours; i++) {
        context.beginPath();
        context.moveTo(x, y);
        context.arc(x, y, radius, i*pieAngle, (i+1)*pieAngle, false);
        context.lineWidth = segmentDepth;
        var hueValue = i * 15;
        context.fillStyle = 'hsl(' + hueValue + ',70%, 60%)';
        // '#'+(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16);
        context.fill();
        context.lineWidth = 2;
        context.strokeStyle = '#444';
        context.stroke();
    }
}
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/gamealchemist/U2tPJ/79/

Answer (score 2):

The width of the ring is controlled by the line `context.lineWidth = segmentDepth;`.  It seems like you forgot that the line width goes into both directions. To make the ring go to the center, change it to `segmentDepth * 2`. However, this will also make the whole graphic twice as big, so you might want to compensate by reducing the `segmentDepth`.