# Is it possible to make a multi-color highlight arc in Sigma.js?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, sigma.js

I'm trying to implement my own `hoverRenderer` to make the highlight ring have multiple colors. So I took the `drawHover` in [src/rendering/canvas/hover.ts line 58](https://github.com/jacomyal/sigma.js/blob/1a76bc15fe41339c0ae93b650b7e5eb634c9ce6d/src/rendering/canvas/hover.ts#L58) and replaced

```js
context.arc(data.x, data.y, data.size + PADDING, 0, Math.PI * 2);
context.closePath();
context.fill();
```

with

```js
        const [fillStart, fillEnd, fillRadius] = [0, Math.PI * 2, data.size + PADDING];
        // compute segment arc radian
        const arcRadian = (fillEnd - fillStart) / data.highlightColor.length;

        // draw the highlight ring/arc in different colors specified in highlightColor
        for (let index = 0; index < data.highlightColor.length; index++) {
            context.arc(
                data.x,
                data.y,
                fillRadius + 5,
                fillStart,
                fillStart + arcRadian
            );
            context.fillStyle = data.highlightColor[index];
            context.fill();
            fillStart += arcRadian;
        }
        context.closePath();
```

Even though my `data.highlightColor` was set to `['#FF2301', '#D53032', '#2F4538']`, the arc I got was still single colored. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25032010/html5-canvas-how-to-split-circle-to-x-parts) has a similar implementation and achieves the effect I want. Is there any restriction imposed by Sigma that prevents this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `beginPath` is required in each drawing. The following should work

```js
        for (let index = 0; index < data.highlightColor.length; index++) {
            context.beginPath();
            context.arc(
                data.x,
                data.y,
                fillRadius + 5,
                fillStart,
                fillStart + arcRadian
            );
            context.fillStyle = data.highlightColor[index];
            context.fill();
            fillStart += arcRadian;
        }
```